# Why NSdictionary changed the positions index when i convert string to dictionary?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to convert JSON string to the dictionary. This is my JSON string. But when I convert to dictionary it totally different change the position of key according to JSON string it doesn't show as it is. How can I get a dictionary as what I get into the JSON string? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
     let p_billing_detail = dicData.value(forKey: "p_billing_detail") as! String


// p_billing_detail = "{"propertytax":{"1":{"companyname":"Tax corporation","taxnumber":"78645","dueamount":"1200","previousamount":"1000","description":"The Billing History section of your Billing Details has a link to your Transaction History tab, which has a record of your upcoming and past invoices.","lastpaidon":"2017-08-09","title":"propertytax"}},"gas":{"1":{"companyname":"Gas Corporation","taxnumber":"C11111245","dueamount":"757","previousamount":"1234567","lastpaidon":"2017-08-09","description":"The Billing History section of your Billing Details has a link to your Transaction History tab, which has a record of your upcoming and past invoices.","title":"gas"}},"electricity":{"1":{"companyname":"Electricity Firm","taxnumber":"E1212123","dueamount":"1000","previousamount":"50","lastpaidon":"2017-08-09","description":"The Billing History section of your Billing Details has a link to your Transaction History tab, which has a record of your upcoming and past invoices.","title":"electricity"},"2":{"companyname":"Acme Corporation","taxnumber":"4rt5454","dueamount":"767868","previousamount":"67867","lastpaidon":"2017-08-09","description":"The Billing History section of your Billing Details has a link to your Transaction History tab, which has a record of your upcoming and past invoices.","title":"electricity"}},"telecommunication":{"1":{"companyname":"Tele Corp","taxnumber":"C12341234","dueamount":"5656","previousamount":"978787","lastpaidon":"2017-08-09","description":"The Billing History section of your Billing Details has a link to your Transaction History tab, which has a record of your upcoming and past invoices.","title":"telecommunication"},"2":{"companyname":"Tele Corp","taxnumber":"123132","dueamount":"50","previousamount":"500","lastpaidon":"2017-08-23","description":"The Billing History section of your Billing Details has a link to your Transaction History tab, which has a record of your upcoming and past invoices.","title":"telecommunication"}}}"


    let objeArray = self.convertToDictionary(text: p_billing_detail) as! NSDictionary


  func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> Any? {

            if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                do {
                    return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                } catch {
                    //print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have *position indexes* because dictionaries are unordered by definition.

Comment: so sir is there any option? To get the result as what I get in string?

Comment: And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use its native counterpart, Dictionary.

Comment: The values of dictionaries are retrieved by keys. The order actually doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks vadian for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered by their nature—you don’t access elements by index but rather by key. This is also true for your JSON source. The order of the elements in your JSON string ist a pure matter of presentation, not a matter of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary does not maintain the order of keys. If you want that, you can keep the keys inside a separate array. But for that you would have to write your own JSON parser.